# How to send id between kendo grid and controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is my view:

```
 <%= Html.Kendo().Grid<Azalia.Models.DocsAn>("docs")
          .Name("docs")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {

                  columns.Bound(c => c.DocName);
                  columns.Command(com => com.Custom("More")
                      .Action("FileEditor", "TellMeMore", new { Id = 1 })).Width(10);
              })
           .Pageable(pageable => pageable
           .Refresh(true)
           .PageSizes(true)
           .ButtonCount(5))

    %>
```

Controller  TellMeMore

```
        public ActionResult FileEditor(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Model DocsAn : 
Id and DocName property

I would like to get number of row after click instead of number 1 in controller .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not telerik expert but it should be something like this
remove `new { Id = 1 }` and 
give a name to command

```
Name("ClickButton").Action("FileEditor", "TellMeMore")).Width(10);
```

later add this script

```
<script>

$(".k-grid-ClickButton").on("click", function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    if (selectedData) {
        var selectedId = selectedData.Id;
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        href += "?id=" +selectedId ;
        $(this).attr("href", href);
    }
});

</script>
```

- dont forget to bound Id

  columns.Bound(c => c.Id);